# R - Riverplot package uses - Sankey diagram

Tags: r, plot, charts, sankey-diagram, riverplot

I try to draw a sankey chart using [riverplot package](http://logfc.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/riverplot/) by January. However my cases is quite complex and I haven't found way to fix my chart so I post this questions, hope this help either find some answer to my questions or way to improve the packages.

My charts as below. As you can see my chart in the 1st image have the node's status overlap each others and not readable. Is it possible to display the nodes name on the side of the chart, and each nodes name will next to the lane that it stand for. The ideas display in the second image below where we have multiple lanes and then the status should be on the side to explain what is lane mean.

Thank you very much!

[image]

[image]

My cases is difficult to generate a sample yet I reuse January sample included in riverplot package with some modification. Here it is

```
library(riverplot)
temp <- function () {
ret <- list(nodes = 
                data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:8], x = c(1,2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1), 
                           labels = c(NA, NA, "Node C Node C Node C", rep(NA, 4), "Node H Node H Node H"), 
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
            styles = list(A = list(col = "#00990099",
                                   lty = 0, textcol = "white"), 
                          H = list(col = "#FF000099", textcol = "white"), 
                          B = list(col = "#00006699", textcol = "white"),                                                                                                                                                                           F = list(col = "yellow"), D = list(col = "#00FF0099")))
ret$edges <- data.frame(N1 = c("A", "A", "A", "H", "H", "H", 
                               "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), N2 = 
                            c("B", "C", "D", "D", "F", "G", "D", "F", "D", "E", "F"), 
                        Value = c(10, 20, 5, 10, 10, 20, 5, 10, 20, 15, 10), stringsAsFactors = F)
rownames(ret$nodes) <- ret$nodes$ID
class(ret) <- c(class(ret), "riverplot")
return(ret)
} 
x <- temp(x) 
plot(x)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html)?

Comment: I reuse the standard sample within the riverplot package. The sample have Node C name overlap other node name which make it slightly difficult to read similar to my case but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `srt` argument to `riverplot` plus shorter labels the answer?

```
ret <- list(nodes = 
              data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:8], x = c(1,2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1), 
    #                     labels = c(NA, NA, "Node C Node C Node C", rep(NA, 4), "Node H Node H Node H"), 
            labels = c(NA, NA, "Node C", rep(NA, 4), "Node H"), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
            styles = list(A = list(col = "#00990099",
                                   lty = 0, textcol = "white"), 
                          H = list(col = "#FF000099", textcol = "white"), 
                          B = list(col = "#00006699", textcol = "white")))                                                                                                                                                                           F = list(col = "yellow"), D = list(col = "#00FF0099")))
ret$edges <- data.frame(N1 = c("A", "A", "A", "H", "H", "H", 
                               "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), N2 = 
                          c("B", "C", "D", "D", "F", "G", "D", "F", "D", "E", "F"), 
                        Value = c(10, 20, 5, 10, 10, 20, 5, 10, 20, 15, 10), stringsAsFactors = F)
rownames(ret$nodes) <- ret$nodes$ID
class(ret) <- c(class(ret), "riverplot")

riverplot(ret, srt = 0)
```

[image]