# What is the Name of this Visualization?

Tags: r, rstudio, visualization, data-visualization

The RStudio website has a very interesting visualization as shown below:

https://gallery.shinyapps.io/TSupplyDemand/

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to pin down the source code, package, or even more simply, the name of this visualization.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone was able to point my research in the right direction.  I suspect that knowing the name of the visualization will help me resolve the remaining questions quite quickly.

Comment: Judging from the page, it is *not* a specific visualization but a custom application. Why don't you contact the author?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think he was asking for the name of the diagram and not the application.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram

Comment: @Perfection I didn't think he was. I thought that this was a custom-made visualization though, not a specific type. Which is why I didn't vote to close, and I'll vote to reopen if this question is closed.

Comment: You could also consider the riverplot package and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954562/r-riverplot-package-uses-sankey-diagram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Sankey Diagram, where the width of the edges is proportional to the amount transferred between nodes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22481979/2633645) on SO suggests that rCharts can be used to create such plots.

Comment: Thanks r.bot and lawyeR - That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `networkD3` offers a Sankey chart now, and just for reference `rCharts` is being slowly reimplemented as a `htmlwidget`.  https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3